# Why is Xtext editor getting slowly with large grammars?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, xtext

I'm working on a Xtext-project and right now I have a grammar of the length of ~1300 lines.
However when I change a single thing in my grammar eclipse takes minutes until it's usable again.
Does anybody know why this happens (a java file with >3000 lines is no problem for eclipse) or even how to fix it (apart from splitting the grammar up into multiple files)?
I alredy tried to increase the heap size of eclipse but that didn't change anything.

Best regards Raven

Comment: Do you mean you change a single thing in the *.xtext file and it takes minutes?

Comment: Well not the change itself but right after it eclipse starts doing something (I guess it starts parsing the complete file) and that is taking minutes and until it's finished I can't do anything else in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found out what the problem was:
Parts of my grammar are generated by a program I wrote and it did a few mistakes and therefore I had hundreds of errors in my grammar and this was what made the editor that slowly.

I fixed those mistakes and now eclipse is as fast as expected.